# How to show entries with IF statement based on field

Tags: templating, entries

I'm showing entries on a page. Depending on the value of the field `postAspectRatio`, I would like the layout of this shown entry to change just slightly and thus requiring it's own unique markup.

I've tried to do this using what I know about twig IF syntax but it's not working.

Any help?

```
{% block content %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section('projects').order('postDate asc').limit(500).find() %}

        {% if entry.postAspectRatio == 'Portrait' %}

        <div class="title portrait">
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
                <p><span>{{ entry.studio }}</span>{{ entry.title }}</p>
            </a>
        </div>

        {% endif %}

        {% if entry.postAspectRatio == 'Landscape' %}

        <div class="title landscape">
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
                <p><span>{{ entry.studio }}</span>{{ entry.title }}</p>
            </a>
        </div>

        {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your syntax is right. What type of field is `postAspectRatio`?

Comment: Test the output with `{{ entry.postAspectRatio }}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statements looks correct. You might check that you are testing the value vs. the name (i.e. 'Portrait' vs 'portrait') or printing out the value (using `{{ entry.postAspectRatio }}`) so you can see the output. Also, a 'dryer' way to write this might be:

```
{% block content %}

    {% for entry in craft.entries.section('projects').order('postDate asc').limit(500).find() %}

        <div class="title {{ entry.postAspectRatio|lower }}">
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
                <p><span>{{ entry.studio }}</span>{{ entry.title }}</p>
            </a>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```